The hot chocolate is calling me vs calling my name. Do they mean the same?
I noticed that "the hot chocolate is calling me" is similar to "the hot chocolate is calling my name" in meaning, and I understand those as meaning "I want the hot chocolate".
Do they have the exact same meaning?  If not, what are the nuances?
Thank you.

Yes, they mean essentially the same thing.

Thank you for the comment.

They mean the same and they could be used interchangeably. A third, similar phrase with the same meaning is "The hot chocolate has my name on it"

They're similar, although the source of the metaphor is a little different. "has my name on it" seems like it's derived from a barrista writing the name of the customer on the coffee cup.

Or since it's older than Starbucks, maybe the label on a delivered package.

@Barmar - something 'having your name on it' is a figure of speech with a long history, notably relating to bullets in wartime (there's no point in cowering too much or worrying, because if a bullet has your name on it, it will find you). Perhaps it comes from letters or other types of postal packages.

@MichaelHarvey That sounds right, although it's quite different from the positive aspect of "calling my name"

Has my name on it is less colorful, and certainly less dramatic, less emphatic than the other two and their image of an inanimate object’s calling out to its imminent (and obligated) consumer.

I would argue that “[…] has my name on it” means something slightly, yet significantly, different — it inverts the agency.  Saying that something “[…] is calling {my name}/{to me}” carries an undertone that you are trying to resist the call/allure, while “[…] has my name on it” implies that you have actively/willingly staked a claim to it.  (e.g. “I am on a diet, but the hot chocolate is calling my name!” versus “Brr, it's cold out — when I get home, there's a hot chocolate with my name on it!”)

Thank you Peter Jennings very much for the answer and a new phrase. Also,thank you Barmar, Michael, Paul, and Chronocidal(esp for pointing out the undertone and examples) for the comments.
